# How to dynamically add or remove the next/prev buttons from intro.js tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

I am using intro.js to create a tour through a site, but I need the next/prev buttons to be added dynamically depending on the tootip.

Example: I would like to have the next/prev button on my third tooltip, but not my first and second ones. Reason is I am trying to help the user to navigate through the site by click on the buttons on the site instead of the next button in the tooltip to give a more interactive tour. Here is my code:

```
        want_tour.click(function() {
                    var introguide = introJs();
                    introguide.setOptions({
                          showStepNumbers: false,
                          showBullets: false,
                          showButtons: false,
                          scrollToElement: true,
                          exitOnEsc: true,
                          exitOnOverlayClick: false,
                          steps: [
                                {
                                      element: '#postcodeEntry',
                                      intro: 'Enter Postcode',
                                      position: 'bottom'
                                },
                                {
                                      element: '.home_Intro_Main',
                                      intro: 'Register or Start Shopping',
                                      position: 'bottom'
                                },
                                {
                                      element: '#searchform ',
                                      intro: 'Search',
                                      position: 'bottom'
                                },
                                {
                                      element: '.mainNavigation ',
                                      intro: 'Categories',
                                      position: 'bottom'
                                }
                          ]
                    }); 
                    introguide.start();
                    $('.chk-my-postcode').click(function() {
                          console.log("Clicked: .chk-my-postcode");
                          want_tour.hide();
                          introguide.goToStep(1).start();
                    });
                    $('#startShoppingWeDeliver').click(function() {
                          console.log("Clicked: #startShoppingWeDeliver");
                          introguide.setOption("skipLabel", "ExitOption");
                          introguide.setOptions({ skipLabel: 'ExitOptions', showButtons: true});
                          introguide.goToStep(2).start();
                    }); 
              });
```

Currently the skipLabel tags changes its text by using either setOption() or setOptions() but the required showButtons is not being set to false.

Could you please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

the introjs-disabled class is now added to the 'previous' button on the first step, and the 'next' button on the last step. i really just wanted them hidden, so i added the below to my css. Poof! Done!

```
.introjs-disabled {
     display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Adam Krakow, this is a bad practice to disable CSS.

If IntroJS onKeypress is active, user can only press "Enter" and he will be taked to the next step.